# Accessing DAO Recordset Values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am storing a field name in a variable - and I want to access the value stored in that field by way of DAO Recordset.

My syntax is set-up like the below, but my Debug.Print statement returns

```
idea.Value
```

Instead of the actual value held in the field.  For example, let's say that I have a table called `Test` with a short text field called `idea` that holds the values

> red
> green
> blue

And In my syntax below I would want the `idea.Value` to show those 3 values, but instead of printing the actual value I get the field name printed.  What did I set-up incorrectly for this to occur?

```
Public fieldname As String

fieldname = "ides"

Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    rsInsert.AddNew
    Debug.Print ""& fieldnamea & ".Value"
Loop
```

Comment: Anything between double quotes is a *string literal*. Your `Debug.Print` statement isn't accessing the recordset field in any way, it's just printing what it's told to print: two string literals and a string variable, concatenated. `""&` is completely useless BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    Debug.Print rsInsert.Fields(fieldname).Value
    rsInsert.MoveNext
Loop
```

Note that you're probably better off looking for a tutorial on the web about how recordsets work, than trial and error and asking questions on Stack Overflow on error.

Comment: That Debug.Print statement returns a null value also

Comment: Oh wait - there is one null value in the table...I needed to step thro more than one instance.  Apology.

Comment: Please correct the code, the name of the recordset is `rsSelect` which is used in the `Do While` condition, but `rsInsert` is used inside the loop.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir I can't, since I don't know if OP wanted to iterate through the rsSelect or the rsInsert recordset. Go ask him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below :

```
Public fieldname As String

fieldname = "idea"

Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    Debug.Print rsSelect(fieldname).Value
    rsSelect.MoveNext
Loop
```

Alternatively you can simply do this without using any variable :

```
Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    Debug.Print rsSelect!idea
    rsSelect.MoveNext
Loop
```